# Правописание

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли будет выражения "грамопись" то есть грамотно писать? Их правописание.

Answer (score 7):

Первый раз слышу. Словари тоже не фиксируют. Правда, Яндекс выдал целых 5 случаев употребления. Чем грамопись (грамотное написание) лучше правописания (правильное писание)?

Answer (score 4):

Такого слова нет, разве что допустить образование ещё одного окказионализма). В русском языке есть хорошее слово "правописание" - правильно писать, и Вы это слово хорошо знаете. Правильно означает и грамотно тоже.

Answer (score 2):

**"Грамопись" ?**

Спрашивается, а с какой целью употреблять такое слово? Вот в чём вопрос (как писал Шекспир :-) )

Если вы хотите изобразить, так сказать, что-то *исконно русское* вместо *ненашенского* :) слова **"орфография"**, то знайте, что слово **"грамота"** тоже не русское!

Есть греческое слово **γράμματα** (граммата). Это множественное число от слова γράμμα -- письмо.

А греческое же "орфография" вполне переводится на русский, как "правописание". Русский точный перевод корней орфо- и -графия.

Answer (score 2):

Это либо окказионализм либо неологизм.

Под окказионализмом понимается либо слово, употребленное в крайне необычном значении, либо образование, не фиксируемое нормативными источниками (в данном случае - именно это). А неологизм - недавно придуманное слово еще не вошедшее в оборот. Включая т.н. слова-однодневки.

Очень похоже, что "наше" грамопись придумано как некая замена английскому спеллинг, что как раз и обозначает "правильнописание". Большой нужды в нем не вижу, ибо есть вполне разумные русские аналоги. "Правописание" - почти тоже самое. 
Возможно появление связано с тем, что в русском "орфография" традиционно понимается в узком смысле - только правописание **слов**, пунктуация рассматривается как отдельная дисциплина.

Answer (score 0):

> Это либо окказионализм либо неологизм

Пусть уж лучше будет окказионализмом.